# How to do right relationships between objects Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: Category and Item. Item can have 2 or more categories so I need to have a relationship on categories(maybe one-to-many) from the item I create. But, I also need to fetch that items related to a category(or categories), maybe like this:
`http://example.com/api/items?category_id=5`

Can anyone advice how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you have manytomany relation between Item and Category as

```
class Category:
    .....

class Item:
    category = ManytoMany relation to Category
```

In this case, you can extract Item related to category as following:

Suppose you have Category object as `c1`

```
 c1.item_set.all()
```

Here `c1 = Category.objects.get(id=5)`

Answer (score 1):

Because an item may be in multiple categories and, also, a category may have multiple items between `Category` and `Item` models must be a [**`Many-to-Many`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship which you can define as follows:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    .....
```

and

```
class item(models.Model):
    ....
    categories = modles.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) you can see more details of operations that can be performed using the Python API facilities.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice I would suggest is, add many-to-many relation of category table in your item table.

For example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # Write here your fields name

class Item(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```